# Store day and date in same column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a situation where I need to store day and date(just a date)  in single column in Oracle as below:

```
Column name                                                                                    
Monday                                                                                                
Tuesday                                                   
25
10
```

But I don't like combining string and number in single column. So I want any formula or design where each of these values gets unique identifier and store like below:

```
Column name                  
1 - - - - - refers to Monday              
2............refers Tuesday              
3-----------refers to a actual date 1
```

Above is an imaginary values just for understanding. 
What I need is if have to get all entries with value Monday I should apply some formula and get a number which I should use in select query

Same way if I want to select entries with date =25 then I have to apply same formula and get unique number that represents date 25 and use it in my query

Comment: As everybody confused I am adding one more point that I can not make this column a date type or date stamp.... It is a number type.... So I want to store dates as number and day of the week also as some number..

Comment: And why doesn't 3 refer to Wednesday?

Comment: The example ur seeing is just a made up thing I can refer 3 to Wednesday.... 4 to Thursday...... 5 to Fri 6 to sat and 7 to sun..... But what should I store If I get actual date 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as these are mapped to days if store these values it looks like these entries have days of the week but that should not happen....

Comment: You cannot store that information in a single column. You need two columns for that. Or use a single column defined as `date`

Comment: Why can't we have a formula for which I will pass a day and it generates a unique number and I will store that... Same way I will pass a date it generates a unique number for that date and we will store that.... So while querying also we will use same formula and get the value and search with that

Comment: Even if you find such a formula, this violates the basic principles of good database design. Just add a second column and be done with it. That will be much more flexible and efficient in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Store only the DATE in a column, the day of week is derived from that.

so:

```
  CREATE TABLE junk
  (
  id       number,
  my_date  date 
  );

  insert into junk values ( 123, sysdate );
  insert into junk values ( 234, add_months(sysdate,-123) );
  commit;

  select my_date  "The actual date",
         to_char(my_date,'Day')  "The day of the week",
         to_char(my_date,'Dy') "other way",
         to_char(my_date,'D') "another way"
  from junk;

  The actual date      The day o oth a
  -------------------- --------- --- -
  27-mar-2019 15:28:15 Wednesday Wed 4
  27-dec-2008 15:28:15 Saturday  Sat 7

  2 rows selected.
```

Trying to do anything more than that, you will likely only hurt yourself in the long run (consider how you will maintain things if something is updated .. consider what happens if/when somebody "accidentally" updates 1 of the values, without updating the matching one?  ... because they didn't understand it ... )

```
  -- only pull records on Wednesday
  select *
  from junk
  where to_char(my_date,'D') = 4
  /

          ID MY_DATE
  ---------- --------------------
         123 27-mar-2019 15:28:15

  1 row selected.
```

Comment: I cannot make this column a date type as I mentioned..... I should be storing just a number... And I don't need month and all.... Just date and day of week all should be unique.... I am looking for some kind of formula which will give me unique value for Monday and unique value for a date

Comment: @premkumar: a "date" already identifies the day of the week. Why would you store that redundantly?

Comment: It's not redundant some entries will have date as value and some entries will have day of the week as values from the source I am getting.... But I don't want to combine string and number.... I just want to map all dates to some unique numbers and all day of the week to unique number

Comment: @premkumar  again, we're telling you not to do it that way. Store the date .. and you have ALL that information (plus more) at your fingertips ... it's not wise or maintainable to store it any other way ... sorry,   *shrug*

Comment: Actually it is not so heavily used I can maintain it even if it's a bad idea

Comment: @premkumar  missing the point .. if it's not so heavily used, why not just build it "properly" and simply? why try to overengineer it with overly complex design that's not needed?

Comment: ^1 for calling the table junk :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the to_char() function in oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(date '2019-03-27', 'DAY') day FROM dual;
```

Which will return the day of the week.

Comment: if I get 1 as day of week for Monday then 1 represents Monday then what about actual date 1 how would I store it